# How to find how many times a value is repeated in a SQLite column string?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

This is my code:

```
// here I am getting my values from SQlite db
number = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("number"));
```

This is how I search for the repeated number:

```
String text = number;

List<String> list = Arrays.asList(text.split(" "));

Set<String> uniqueWords = new HashSet<String>(list);

for (String word : uniqueWords) {
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),word + ": " + Collections.frequency(list, word),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                
}
```

My problem is that it shows every value as `-1`.

For example, I have a value in my database 789456 -5 times but it shows as 789456-1,789456-1 and so on.

Comment: Your code seens to count only one occurence of the column number, show your string you got on cur.getString(cur.getColundIndex("number"))

Comment: Your Shift key seems to be broken. I've fixed this post, but if you could get a new keyboard prior to your next question, that would be great.

Comment: @Marcos Vasconcelos i only want one column values

Comment: What the result from cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("number"));  ?

Comment: @ Marcos Vasconcelos it shows all the values stored in the SQlite in this column like 123456,456,789